# Clear canvas context gradually (mouse trail?)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, mouseevent

If you see run the code snippet that i have,  you'll this html canvas drawing thing that is segmented to color the arcs in a gradient.

I'm trying to figure out how to gradually clear the context of old 'arcs' from the tail end of the drawing similar to a 'mouse trail' effect, perhaps similar to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD11J.jpg

I'm thinking, perhaps that somehow, once the `total` counter goes above the `segment` count, it clears itself but im not quite sure how to do that.

Grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction!

```js
var c = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
        colors = [
          {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a:1},
          {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a:1},
        ],
        cIndex = 0, maxColors = colors.length,
        total = 0, segment = 1000,
        isDown = false, px, py;


    setSize();
          
    c.onmousedown = c.ontouchstart = function(e) {
      isDown = true;
      var pos = getPos(e);
      px = pos.x;
      py = pos.y;
    };

    c.onmousemove = c.ontouchmove = function(e) {if (isDown) plot(e)};
    c.onmouseup = c.ontouchend = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      isDown = false
    };

    function getPos(e) {
      // e.preventDefault();
      if (e.touches) e = e.touches[0];
      var r = c.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        x: e.clientX - r.left,
        y: e.clientY - r.top
      }
    }

    function plot(e) {
      var pos = getPos(e);
      plotLine(ctx, px, py, pos.x, pos.y);
      px = pos.x;
      py = pos.y;
    }

    function plotLine(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

      var diffX = Math.abs(x2 - x1),
          diffY = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
          dist = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY),
          step = dist / 50,
          i = 0,
          t, b, x, y;
      
      while (i < dist) {
        t = Math.min(1, i / dist);

        x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * t;
        y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * t;



        // ctx.shadowBlur = 500;
        // ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
        // ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
        // ctx.shadowColor = getColor();

        // console.log(getColor())
        ctx.fillStyle = getColor();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 25, 0, Math.PI*2);

        ctx.fill();
        i += step;
      }
      
      function getColor() {
      
        var r, g, b, a, t, c1, c2;
        
        c1 = colors[cIndex];
        c2 = colors[(cIndex + 1) % maxColors];
        t = Math.min(1, total / segment);
        
        if (++total > segment) {
          total = 0;
          if (++cIndex >= maxColors) cIndex = 0;
        }
      
        r = c1.r + (c2.r - c1.r) * t;
        g = c1.g + (c2.g - c1.g) * t;
        b = c1.b + (c2.b - c1.b) * t;
        a = c1.a + (c2.a - c1.a) * t;
        

        return "rgb(" + (r|0) + "," + (g|0) + "," + (b|0) + "," + (a) + ")";
      }
    }

    window.onresize = setSize;
    function setSize() {
      c.width = window.innerWidth;
      c.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
```

```css
html, body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

 
    body {
      padding: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
```

Comment: The canvas doesn't store previously drawn paths, just the current color of the pixels. If you want to change your path afterwards, the way to do it is to erase the canvas and redraw the path parts you want to keep. If you store the path coordinates in an array, pushing new paths coordinates onto the end of the array and shifting old coordinates off the start of the array. You can rerender the elements in the array, after clearing the canvas, to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: A easy way to do it would be to use this `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.2)";
      ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)` at the beginning of the `plotLine`. Explanation: if you use `rgb(255,255,255)` instead of `rgba(255,255,255,.2)` this will clear the canvas since you cover all the previous drawing s with a white rectangle the size of the canvas. If you use the semitransparent white previous drawing will be gradually covered resulting in a canvas _apparently_ gradual cleared.

Comment: cool! yeah this somewhat does what i was trying to achieve

Comment: The problem with the method @enxaneta exposes is that `alpha(0.2) + alpha(0.2) + alpha(0.2) ...` never comes to `alpha(1)`. You will always have a ghost of your previous drawings.

Comment: @Kaiido yeah i realised that too. do you have a suggestion?